# If cross domain ajax calls are not allowed then how are you supposed to use the google spreadsheet API

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, google-sheets-api

If cross domain ajax calls are not allowed then how are you supposed to do [this](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingRows)? *Note: obsoleted link. Question updated with relevant section from original page in question.*

*From link; (Developer's Guide: Protocol v 2.0 – Google Spreadsheets API):*

#### Add a row

To add a row to the table, start by creating an `<entry>` element containing the relevant data:

```
<entry>
  <gsx:hours>1</gsx:hours>
  <gsx:ipm>1</gsx:ipm>
  <gsx:items>60</gsx:items>
  <gsx:name>Elizabeth Bennet</gsx:name>
</entry>
```

Then determine the appropriate URL to send the entry to, known as the *POST URL*. You can find the POST URL in the list feed's `<link>` element that has `rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post"`.

Next, do any necessary authentication, and create an Authorization header for a new POST request as described in the authentication sections of this document.

In the body of the POST request, place the *Atom `<entry>`* element you created above, using the `application/atom+xml` content type.

Now send the request to the POST URL:

> ```
> POST http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/key/worksheetId/private/full
> ```

Spreadsheets inserts the new row immediately after the last row that appears in the list-based feed, which is to say immediately before the first entirely blank row.

Comment: [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)

Answer (score 3):

Cross domain ajax restrictions are only a browser restriction.  If you make a webservice call from the server or another application, you won't be restricted.  If you need to do an ajax call though, you could proxy the call through your server.

Comment: Do you have any examples of proxying the call through the server?  I'm having the same problems as the OP.

Comment: It depends on the server language you're using.

Comment: I found one using PHP that works for me.  Thanks. For all others viewing this, Zend Framework is a usable solution.  http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html