# Connecting chrome plugin to Java code that calculates values gathered by the plugin

Tags: web-services, plugins, google-chrome-extension

I have a very similar, yet more high level question to [Connecting Google APIs to Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926841/connecting-google-apis-to-chrome-extension) , meaning - how to connect a chrome plugin to a "java code" - i.e. an app that analyses information gathered by the plugin, then connects back to plugin with updated information, so that the plugin can display a relevant message?

I am completely new to any kind of development so please forgive me my question, I'm very embarrassed that I don't even know what to research! Can I think of this as a mini "web service" to understand how the two could communicate?

I'll be grateful for any nudge :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nudge: [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging)

Using this API, you can invoke an external program from a Chrome extension to pass data back and forth.

Comment: This is a perfect article to start with, thank you so much!